# How to add project to Netbeans when all source files are not in webroot?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

The directory structure of my project is like this:-

`/var/www/includes/`
`/var/www/classes/`

`/var/www/public/css/`
`/var/www/public/js/`
`/var/www/public/index.php`

The webroot is `/var/www/public`, so accessing the test domain `localhost.dev` would serve the files inside the `public` directory and hence would run `/var/www/public/index.php`. No need to access like `localhost.dev/public/index.php`

The problem is when I create the project in Netbeans, I have to set the index file so that the project can be debugged using xdebug and Netbeans.

So when adding the project I provided `/var/www` as Project source folder (`Sources Folder`) as the `includes` and `classes` are in this folder. In the next project configuration screen (`Choose Project > Name and Location > file path is taken as Run Configuration`), I'm asked for the `Project URL` and the `index file`. Since the `index.php` file is actually under the `/var/www/public/`, when I browse the file and select it, the url to index page is taken as `localhost.dev/public/index.php` instead of just `localhost.dev/index.php`. This is preventing me from debugging the project.

Can anyone please point out how to add projects to Netbeans when all the source files are not in web root and the project is to be debugged using xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bad practice to put all the project files directly in `/var/www`.

I think you will never see that in real deployed projects. So my first recommendation will be to change the way you are structuring your project. If that's not possible, in Netbeans select `/var/www/public` as the Project folder.

If Netbeans need references to the folders in `/var/www`, create symbolic folders inside public pointing to those in `/var/www`.

The last resource you have is to create a rewrite rule in Apache to make `localhost.dev/public` be the same as `localhost.dev`. You can look for this in [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set up with one minor difference: my setup uses a remote site on my local development server. On the "Run Configuration" window of the project properties, I set "Run As" to "Remote Web Site (FTP, SFTP)". I don't think this affects the information in my answer, but I'm mentioning it just in case.

Go to the "Sources" window of your project properties, find the entry for "Web Root", click "Browse" and select the `/var/www/public` directory. That should cause xDebug to use [localhost.dev/index.php](http://localhost.dev/index.php). You'll notice when you go to the "Run Configuration" window and browse for the Index File that the browse window will start in "public" rather than "www".

**An important note about this type of configuration that caused me a great deal of frustration.**

When using xDebug, you'll want to be able to set breakpoints in and work with the files outside of the web root (public) directory. Because you've set the web root to `/var/www/public`, you won't be able to work with the files in `/var/www/includes` or `/var/www/classes`.

The thing you need to do is to add the files outside of your web root to the Global Include Path.

There are two methods for adding directories to your Global Include Path, which one you use depends on how you've configured your project.

In your case, the external directories are included in your project, so you need to add them via the "Options" interface. Go to *Tools->Options* and select the "PHP" tab, then add the `/var/www/includes` and `/var/www/classes` folders to the Global Include Path.

The other method for adding files to the Global Include Path is for files that are located outside of your project source folder. For directories like `/var/folder_outside_www/`, you use the "PHP Include Path" window in the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a better way but I use this steps:

1. Menu:**Project Properties** -> Link:**Run Configuration** -> Button:**Advanced**
2. Debug URL, choose: **Ask Every Time**
3. Path Mapping, Server Path: http://localhost.dev/ ,Project Path: /var/www/public/

Now, when you start Debugging process, Netbeans will display **Specify URL** pop-up which you can change from http://localhost.dev/public/index.php into http://localhost.dev/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Set /var/www/public as project folder (contain netbeans project folder) and include in project properties /var/www/includes/ and /var/www/classes/ as global include directories. Or best way use PHPStorm.